# Why my flexipage doesn't show on Community Record Detail page

Tags: customer-community, flexipages

Can anyone please help me with the page layout. In Salesforce I have created a flexipage and assigned it to the profile and the app for community users but on the community the page is still not updated. I want the detail to shown on the left panel and related list to the right panel but it is showing with 2 tabs. Please help why it is not showing on community and how I can enable it.

Answer (score 2):

Flexipages created in Lightning does **not** affect community. For community you need to create new page and then add these components via `New Page`, or edit any existing page.

[image]

Then follow the instructions to create a page in community and drag drop same components as selected in lightning app builder.

Make sure this is `checked` to retrieve and deploy site pages programmatically.

[image]

Finally retrieve your site in `json` format and deploy that to higher environments.
File structure would be like this when retrieved.
[image]

Comment: But then how come I was able to update it on community in other org where it was already implemented. Today I am starting from scratch to learn community but in other org when I had been asked then I had just done in Lightning flexipage only and changes were reflecting.

Comment: Also when I select New Page it gives me 2 options. Which one should I select? and will it be giving the pages from Lightning app builder? if yes then from where I need to drag and drop. Please clarify.

Comment: I highly doubt that it would have ever worked as lightning record pages are only meant for lightning experience according to document. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm&type=5

Comment: For more on community builder check this : https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_edit_pages.htm&type=5

Comment: Ohh. then not sure. Could you please guide me the steps for creating new page. Like which one should I choose and where should I put this page under the tab?